# How to compare the contents of two PDF files?

Tags: pdf, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compare the differences between two PDF files?](https://superuser.com/questions/46123/how-to-compare-the-differences-between-two-pdf-files)

I'm currently summarizing a PDF of a Course I will need to do again next year,
it is possible that the contents of the PDF will change which would introduce mistakes in my summary.

Is there a way to view the changes between two versions of a PDF file?

Comment: Indeed is, but I didn't found that one... I'll try to improve it.

Comment: Actually, the possible duplicate at http://superuser.com/q/46123/48480 is a operating system dependend question (windows) while this one (and most of the answers) are independend from the os - or prefer *NIX...

Comment: Woops, but well... There are enough answers in both. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using pdftotext of the xpdf toolbox before to export the content as plain text and compare it with my favourite diff tool. Right now I found [pdfdiff](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/cremersc/misc/pdfdiff.html), a python skript, which does exactly, what I did manually before. A quick test showed, that it does what it should.

So thanks for your question which made me look for a new, useful tool.

**Edit**:

I would suggest using it with [meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/), a great diff tool, which is supported by pdfdiff.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out in the future... If it works great I'll accept your answer, else I'll bump my question. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You want to use [i‑net PDF content comparer](http://inetsoftware.de/products/pdf-content-comparer).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out in the future... If it works great I'll accept your answer, else I'll bump my question. :-)

Answer (score -1):

My first answer would be to check the file size, or if you want something more exact, simply do an MD5 checksum verification (on mac, it's /sbin/md5 vi command line). 
For example if you have files a.pdf and a.newer.pdf, you can do this:

```
md5 -q a.pdf && md5 -q a.newer.pdf
```

which should return something like

```
e097902c53d9066aaf679037b6432bdb
920621db3765f6d580a498035b587f67
```

Even a small change will cause a huge hash difference.

Comment: Yeah, I know about md5, but I want to compare the contents.