# Tool for performing a PDF Diff?

Tags: pdf, diff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compare the differences between two PDF files?](https://superuser.com/questions/46123/how-to-compare-the-differences-between-two-pdf-files)

Are there any tools available for performing a diff between two PDF files?  Or am I better off just extracting the text and comparing it in diff?

Comment: Are you referring to [third-party tools](http://superuser.com/questions/46123/how-to-compare-the-differences-between-two-pdf-files) or only built-in tools like `diff`?

Answer (score 4):

**DiffPDF**

DiffPDF is used to compare two PDF files—textually or visually.

DiffPDF can compare two PDF files. It offers three comparison modes: Words, Characters, and Appearance.

http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf.html

Answer (score 1):

The [Portable Document Format (PDF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) is a binary file format.  Although there are provisions in the specification to *not* compress the ASCII text in the file (assuming the text is aligned to 8-bit boundaries), most PDF files are compressed by default to save space (even lightly).  For this reason, it would be impossible to directly `diff` the binary files (it's likely the entire file will have changed).

The easiest and most reliable method is, as your intuition led you, to extract the text and compare *that* using `diff`.